# rdp to vm server on home network over wifi

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008

I have a Win 2008 R2 VM instance running on my desktop. I can RDP to it from the desktop it is on but when I try to RDP it from my laptop on the same wifi connection it comes up with "Server Not Found" error. I can ping the VM server from my laptop though.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same IP address for VM from desktop and laptop?

Answer (score 0):

What version of RDP are you using on your laptop?  Make sure the RDP settings are as follows:
Check the radio button for 'Allow connections from computers running any version of Remote Desktop (less secure)".  This is in the RDP setting of your 2008 server.  Just type remote into the search bar of the start menu.

Comment: Thank You Ryan. Will do exactly that and will come back to you.